# Can I have 2 header locations in PHP?

Tags: php

So, I know my code was working and I have tried un-doing all steps to see where the bug is, but I am still keep getting an error

> my php id=0.

Can you guys show me how I can fix my code up?

The error is as follows:

> undefined variable list_id. It works on my localmachine but not when
>   uploaded to server.

Thanks.

The following is my code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
  $list_id = intval(($_GET['id']));
  try {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items where id =' . $list_id;
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
  } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
  }
  $list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($list == FALSE) {

    header("location: index.php");
  } 


}

if ($list_id == 0) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly you'll soon see why you're getting that error. Your line `if ($list_id == 0) {` is outside the conditional block that would set `$list_id`, so it's always executed, whether or not `$list_id` has been initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are a few issues here. I have added the comments inline.

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $list_id = intval($_GET['id']); //was double parenthesis here
    try {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM items where id =' . $list_id;
            $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    $list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count = count($list); //count result and use for comparison instead of false
    if ($count === 0) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    } 

} else {
    header("location: index.php"); //if no $_GET, redirect
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is instantiate the variable `$list_id` :

```
$list_id = 0; // <-- HERE

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $list_id = intval(($_GET['id']));
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want to redirect to the index if there is no `id` parameter. Since you already check for its presence, redirect in the `else` clause. Remove the last block and add:

```
else
{
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

You may want to add `exit;` after the `header()` call in the `if` block as well, so that code that uses the database further down isn't executed.

Comment: I would recommend to ALWAYS add an `exit` after any Location header, this would avoid bad surprises. Also, Location URIs should be absolute, so the correct syntax would be `header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/fullpath-to-index.php");`